# In android Canvas How to draw a circle and move object along the circle and show the percentage in middle of circle how?

Tags: android

I want this example

pls help me...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IV7LL.png)

Answer (score 1):

In your layout include the following `ProgressBar` with a specific drawable (*note you should get the width from dimensions instead*). The max value is important here:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:max="500"
    android:progress="0"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular" />
```

Now create the drawable in your resources with the following shape. Play with the radius (you can use `innerRadius` instead of `innerRadiusRatio`) and thickness values.

**circular (Pre Lollipop OR API Level < 21)**

```
   <shape
        android:innerRadiusRatio="2.3"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thickness="3.8sp" >
        <solid android:color="@color/yourColor" />
   </shape>
```

**circular ( >= Lollipop OR API Level >= 21)**

```
    <shape
        android:useLevel="true"
        android:innerRadiusRatio="2.3"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thickness="3.8sp" >
        <solid android:color="@color/yourColor" />
     </shape>
```

*useLevel* is **"false"** by default in API Level 21 (Lollipop) .

**Start Animation**

Next in your code use an `ObjectAnimator` to animate the progress field of the `ProgessBar` of your layout.

```
ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt (progressBar, "progress", 0, 500); // see this max value coming back here, we animale towards that value
animation.setDuration (5000); //in milliseconds
animation.setInterpolator (new DecelerateInterpolator ());
animation.start ();
```

**Stop Animation**

```
progressBar.clearAnimation();
```

P.S. unlike examples above, it give smooth animation.

Comment: Let me know if you need more help! Please accept the answer if helped.